# How to dinamically change the shift periods if value is NaN in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF (simplified):

```
value
1
4
2
NaN
9
8
7
```

For example, when I apply the function shift(3)+current_row I get:

```
value  result
1      NaN
4      NaN
2      NaN  
NaN    NaN
9      13
8      10
7      NaN
```

But what I need is if a value is NaN, try with periods=N-1:

```
value  result
1      1       shift(3)=NAN -> shift(2)=NAN -> shift(1)=NAN -> current_value
4      5       shift(3)=NAN -> shift(2)=NAN -> shift(1)=1 + current_value
2      3       shift(3)=NAN -> shift(2)=1 + current_value
NaN    1       shift(3)=1 + if current_value == NaN then 0 else current_value
9      13      shift(3)=4 + current_value
8      10      shift(3)=2 + current_value
7      16      shift(3)=NaN -> shift(2)=9 + current_value
```

If it's possible, in the spirit of the pythonic way.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the `value` column for the periods in the range `3...1`, then create a dataframe from these shifted columns and backfill along the index axis to fill the `NaN` values, then using `iloc` select the first row and add this row with the `value` column

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].shift(3 - i) for i in range(3)).bfill().iloc[0]
df['result'] = df['value'].add(s, fill_value=0)
```

---

```
   value  result
0    1.0     1.0
1    4.0     5.0
2    2.0     3.0
3    NaN     1.0
4    9.0    13.0
5    8.0    10.0
6    7.0    16.0
```